# Convert string Month-Year to datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my dataframe called 'date' as below:

```
Date
Jan-1981
Feb-1981
Mar-1981
.
.
Sep-2005
.
Dec-2008
```

Is there a way to convert this into datetime format so the default format is DD/MM/YYYY where DD is always 01. eg.

Expected 'Date'

```
01-01-1981
01-02-1982
.
.
.
.
.
01-12-2008
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If need datetimes use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print (df)
0 1981-01-01
1 1981-02-01
2 1981-03-01
3 2005-09-01
4 2008-12-01
```

If need custom format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), but datetimes format is lost and get strings (objects):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

print (df)
         Date
0  01-01-1981
1  01-02-1981
2  01-03-1981
3  01-09-2005
4  01-12-2008
```

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason `pd.to_datetime` doesnt parse dates directly (happened to me once where the date format of data was YYYYMMDD with no separators at all) you can get away by using datetime.strptime first, in your case :

```
import datetime as dt


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(lambda x: dt.strptime(x, '%b-%Y')))
```

Note : the reason you *still* need to use `pd.to_datetime` is because the datetime's and pandas' date-data type are different :

datetime.strptime returns a `datetime` object cf [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

`pandas.to_datetime` returns a `Timestamp` or `datetime64` cf [pandas' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)